# An ssrs problem:how to display separation line below the row with condition

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a report in ssrs 2008.

In this report we are displaying the records of 
current product and their match records of each product description.

Each current product has one match records or more than one match. There is a requirement of putting a line of separation below of each last match row of each current product.

I have add  a rectangle below the group of current product and match and set an expression  in hidden property of rectangle like this..

```
=IIF(Fields!Current_Product.Value= "Current Product",True,False)
```

It works nice but it is displaying the line below each match records which I don't want.I wanted that line should be display below the last match records for each current product.

How do I do this...

Please someone respond ...

Comment: Is this in a table or tablix? Is there a grouping?

Comment: yes this is under a row group say name row1.

Comment: Inside a tablix table1 ,under which there is a row group row1